# Console.log return both undefined and correct value

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm learning Nodejs using socket.io. In a basic chat in command line, I want to list the sockets connected to the server.

My approach was to store a couple socketID/username in a hash map. when the user type `/ls`, it sends a message to the server that will trigger an handler that will send the hashmap to the user that will then display.

Client side:

```js
function chat_command(cmd, arg) {
    switch (cmd) {
.
.
.
        case 'ls':
            socket.emit('send', {sender: nick ,action: 'list'});
            break;
.
.
.

socket.on('message', function (data) {

.
.
.
    // List all connected clients
    else if(data.action === 'list'){
        console.log(data.list, 'bug');
        rl.prompt(true);
    }
.
.
.
```

Server Side:

```js
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    socket.on('send', function (data) {

        if (data.type === 'notice') { //update the hasmap with the name
            connectedSockets[socket.id] = data.nick;
            // console.log(connectedSockets);
        }

        if (data.action === 'broadcast') {
            io.sockets.emit('broadcast', data);
        }

        if (data.action === 'list') {
            console.log(connectedSockets , 'ok')
            socket.emit('message', {action:'list', list: connectedSockets});

        }
        else{
            io.sockets.emit('message', data);
        }
    });
```

It works fine at the exception that the client will first display the hashmap as undefined then properly whereas a console.log prior to the socket.emit confirm that the hash map is defined and populated. it returns the following:

```js
> undefined bug
> { bjHo78hGv9QJbElQAAAB: 'hello' } bug
```

instead of

```js
> { bjHo78hGv9QJbElQAAAB: 'hello' } bug
```

An quick fix would be to replace

```js
if (data.action === 'list')
```

by

```js
if (data.action === 'list'&& data.list !== undefined)
```

But I don't still don't understand it would print `undefined` then the hashmap. How comes the code is executed twice on different values when the hashmap was never undefined in the first place.  It really bugs me! Am I missing something obvious?

Any insights would be highly appreciated. Thanks you.

Edit: here a console.trace, might be useful to someone.

```
Trace: undefined bug
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/td1-Nanoboss/startercode/client side/client.js:87:17)
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:133:20)
    at Socket.onevent (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js:278:10)
    at Socket.onpacket (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js:236:12)
    at Manager.<anonymous> (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
    at Manager.Emitter.emit (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:133:20)
    at Manager.ondecoded (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js:345:8)
    at Decoder.<anonymous> (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:133:20)
    at Decoder.add (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:251:12)

Trace: { q6iF1NWEoiagjYwaAAAA: 'max', FudzkqUMYrrvp_u7AAAB: 'ben' } bug
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/td1-Nanoboss/startercode/client side/client.js:87:17)
    at Socket.Emitter.emit (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:133:20)
    at Socket.onevent (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js:278:10)
    at Socket.onpacket (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/socket.js:236:12)
    at Manager.<anonymous> (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
    at Manager.Emitter.emit (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:133:20)
    at Manager.ondecoded (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js:345:8)
    at Decoder.<anonymous> (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-bind/index.js:21:15)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:133:20)
    at Decoder.add (/Users/soyanchardon/Documents/GitHub/iotProject/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:251:12)
```

Comment: Try to replace your `console.log` with `console.trace` to see where the duplicated call is coming from.

Comment: @rafealo thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the console.trace return exactly the same thing. I'll include it in my post.